# need some html/css assistance to figure out why some gap showing up on the page

Tags: html, css

I am not a web developer, but I have very basic knowledge about html/css. In one of the page, I cannot figure out why there is a gap between the title and content of the page and why the content is going out of frame like highlighted in the pic below. Can one of you look into it and help me out? I am sure there are issues with this page, however the developer does not want to admit or not willing to fix.

The site address is:
[new Test News](http://stylezworld.com/projects/bmfs/news/10)

[image]

Comment: please provide a [mcve] in the question itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Apply to the footer (class="mt-5") the following css properties:

   ```
   position: fixed;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   ```
2. Remove the min-height rule from the middle section (class= "row m-0")

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. you suggestion works! You are awesome!

Comment: You are most welcome